# How to install init-checkconf for upstart?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart, init

Upstart is installed, but init-checkconf is not.  Any ideas how to get both?

```
$ sudo init-checkconf
sudo: init-checkconf: command not found
$ sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep upstart
upstart                     install
$ uname -a
Linux VM1 2.6.32-38-server #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:26:59 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're running Ubuntu Lucid (10.04)? `init-checkconf` was introduced in Ubuntu Natty (11.04):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/TechnicalOverviewUpstart

Note that it is possible to build a more recent version of Upstart for Lucid, but there is no officially packaged version. Note that it is not just a case of compiling upstart, you would also need to upgrade libnih and dbus and possibly other libraries.

Comment: Bummer, thanks for the info though